# Spring data JPA transaction delete and save

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using the spring data JPA CrudRepository extension for persisting and getting data. I have to delete and save the record at the same time in transaction.

**My Repository layer**

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<TableEntity, TableEntityPK> {
        @Query("SELECT u FROM TableEntity u where u.TableEntityPK.clientID=:clientID")
        List<TableEntity> findAllByClient(@Param("clientID") String clientID);

        @Transactional
        @Modifying
        @Query("DELETE FROM TableEntity u where u.TableEntityPK.clientID=:clientID and u.TableEntityPK.eventId in :eventIds")
        void deleteAllEventByClientID(@Param("clientID") String clientID,@Param("eventIds") Set<Integer> eventIds);
}
```

Firstly I am calling delete and then save, keeping the method transactional.  But exception thrown after deleteAllEventByClientID before saving removes data from the table and save skips. How to do delete and save in transection

```
@Service
public class DataServiceImpl {

    @Transactional
    public List<TableEntity> createEvent() { 
        dataRepository.deleteAllEventByClientID(subAccount.get("clientId"),eventIds);
        dataRepository.saveAll(data);
    }


}
```

It shoud rollback in case of

```
dataRepository.deleteAllEventByClientID(subAccount.get("clientId"),eventIds);
throws new Exception("forced exception");
        dataRepository.saveAll(data);
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting when deleting?

Comment: It’s getting deleted but not delete and save is not transactional @tomkab

Comment: The whole process seems to me badly designed. If I have understood, you want to delete, keep transaction active while you do something else that can throw an exception, and in this case rollback the deletion. If instead everything runs fine, you want to continue your transaction and make also a saveAll. It is unclear what should happen in case saveAll raises an exception, but it seems not interesting here. Are you sure that you can't model your transaction in a different way?

Comment: @Sumeet I am referring to the exception you mention: `But exception thrown after deleteAllEventByClientID before saving removes data from the table and save skips`. Could you add the exception to the description?

Comment: Delete and save should happen in block , if either of them fails it should roll back . In individual Delete and save of repository is translational but how to make both combined as transactional together